# Porque al compilar en NetBeans no me devuelve nada?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, compilar

Estoy haciendo una suma y conversion octal de dos números, pero al compilar no hace la operación.Estoy llamando los metodos de mi clase desde el main. No he podido encontrar mi error. Dejo mi código (ojo que voy empezando en esto)

```
package octal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConversorSuma {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int suma = num1+num2;

    public ConversorSuma() {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public int sumaleer (){
       System.out.print("Ingrese una cifra: ");
       int num1 = leer.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Ingresa otra cifra");
       int num2 = leer.nextInt();
       System.out.println("La suma en base dies es :"+suma);
       System.out.print("\noctal:\t\t");
       octal(suma);

       return suma;
    }

    //METODO RECURSIVO PARA TRANSFORMAR A OCTAL 
    public int octal(int N){      
        if(N < 8) System.out.print(N);
        else {
            octal(N/8);
           System.out.print(N%8);
        }      
        return N;
    }
}
```

---

```
package octal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Octal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConversorSuma obj = new ConversorSuma();
        obj.sumaleer();
        obj.octal(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuestión de terminologias: *Compilar* solo genera los binarios (`.class`) a partir de los fuentes (`.java`). No significa que el programa que se ha compilado se ejecute. ¿Estás seguro que quieres decir *compilar*?

Comment: La verdad es que me referia a que no hace la operacion, si compila. Mi error gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, te falto poner el Scanner, la variables no se pueden sumar antes que les des el valor y por ultimo para retornar el valor no puedes poner suma tiene que ser la funcion octal.

```
public class ConversorSuma {
int num1;
int num2;

public ConversorSuma() {
this.num1 = num1;
this.num2 = num2;
}
public int  sumaleer (){
 Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Ingrese una cifra: ");
int num1 = leer.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingresa otra cifra");
int num2 = leer.nextInt();
int suma = num1+num2;
System.out.println("La suma en base diez es :"+suma);
System.out.print("\noctal:\t\t");



 return octal(suma); 
}



//METODO RECURCIVO PARA TRANSFORMARA A OCTAL 
public int octal(int N){      
if(N < 8) System.out.print(N);
else {
    octal(N/8);
   System.out.print(N%8);
}      
return N;

}
}
```

En el main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

ConversorSuma obj = new ConversorSuma();
obj.sumaleer();
System.out.println(""); 

}
```

Comment: Gracias hermano, ya regreso el resultado, solo que ahora el valor octal lo devuelve con dos ceros de mas.

Comment: Fíjate en el main, estas repitiendo la función octal por eso los ceros.

Comment: Ya lo solucione. .Era en esta linea  `System.out.println(obj.octal());` En ves de eso imprimi sumaleer, solo que ahora despues de realizar la operacion no para y vuelve a llamar la funcion.